# Mysql assigning value to a variable and echo it

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this code that stores the sum from column total `table_2013` and store it to `$total2013`. Now I want to echo the sum and I want also to echo the sum of `total2013` plus the sum of `total2014` and instead of printing the sum I got a

> "Resource id #4"

```
            $t2013 ="SELECT SUM(total) FROM table_2013";
            $total2013 = (mysql_fetch_assoc($t2013));

            $t2014 ="SELECT SUM(total) FROM table_2014";
            $total2014 = (mysql_fetch_assoc($t2014));

            echo "$total2013";
            echo "$total2014";

            echo "$total2013 + $total2014";
```

Comment: Where are the comment pointing out that he shouldn't use the mysql_* functions anymore?

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing the queries. Execute them -

```
$t2013 ="SELECT SUM(total) FROM table_2013";
$total2013 = (mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($t2013)));

$t2014 ="SELECT SUM(total) FROM table_2014";
$total2014 = (mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($t2014)));
```

You need to provide the column name also -

```
echo $total2013['SUM(total)'] + $total2014['SUM(total)'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }


$t2013 ="SELECT SUM(total) as total2013 FROM table_2013";
$result2013=mysqli_query($con,$t2013);
// Associative array
$row2013=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2013);
$total2013 = $row['total2013'];

$t2014 ="SELECT SUM(total) as total2014  FROM table_2014";
$result2014=mysqli_query($con,$t2014);
// Associative array
$row2014=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2014);
$total2014 = $row['total2014'];

                echo "total2013";
                echo "total2014";

                echo $toal = $total2013 +  $total2014;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run query first:

```
$t2013 ="SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM table_2013";
$q2013 = mysql_query($t2013);
$r2013 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2013);
$total2013 = $r2013['total'];

$t2014 ="SELECT SUM(total) AS total FROM table_2014";
$q2014 = mysql_query($t2014);
$r2014 = mysql_fetch_assoc($q2014);
$total2014 = $r2014['total'];

echo "$total2013";
echo "$total2014";

echo "$total2013 + $total2014";
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors.
1. Your query is not executing.
2. you are echoing a string (echo "$total2013 + $total2014";) at last. It should echo the same thing you put inside "...", it will not sum up those two variables. You should echo as follows:

```
echo $total2013 + $total2014;
```

Thanks